# Stuck with Ionic ScreenOrientation

Tags: ionic3, screen-orientation

I am using Ionic 3. I did

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
npm install @ionic-native/screen-orientation
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';

@NgModule({

   providers: [
     ScreenOrientation,
     ...
```

On my `page.ts`:

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';

ionViewDidLoad() {
this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE);
```

Vs Code is not showing any error, but I get following error during runtime:

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at ScreenOrientation.lock(http://10.18.2.70:8100/build/vendor.js:...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
declare var window;

ionViewDidLoad() {
    window.screen.orientation.lock('landscape');
}
```

Comment: Getting error: `Property 'orientation' does not exist on type 'Screen'`

Comment: `Property 'orientation' does not exist on type 'Screen'. Did you mean 'msOrientation'? `

Comment: As I see, ‘screen’ should be in lowercase. Try this once else share your piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

For ionic3 use:

```
npm install @ionic-native/screen-orientation@4
```